# Rails 4 - showing errors for nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-forms

I have a `belongs_to` and `has_many` association between two models.  I have a user creation form that creates the user and in the process, creates an organization and associates the two.  I have a validation for the presence of an organization name.  If that validation fails, i'd like the `Organiation` to add the `Name cannot be blank` error to the same hash of error messages that the `User` has.  Basically, creating one list of error messages.

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  belongs_to :organization

  validates_presence_of :display_name
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true

  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Here's my create action:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
  if params[:user][:organization][:access_code].blank?
    # create new organization
    @access_code = "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(16)}#{Time.now.to_i}"
    @organization = Organization.create(name: params[:user][:organization][:name], access_code: @access_code)
    @user.organization_id = @organization.id
    @user.is_admin = true
  else
    # try and add someone to an organization
    @organization = Organization.find(:all, conditions: ["name = ? AND access_code = ?", params[:user][:organization][:name], params[:user][:organization][:access_code]])
    if @organization.empty?
      flash.now[:error] = "No organization has been found with that name and access code."
      render :new
      return
    else
      @user.organization_id = @organization.first.id
    end
  end
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been successfully created! Check your email for a confirmation link to activate your account."
    redirect_to sign_in_path
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong! Please try again."
    render :new
  end
end
```

Here's my view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign Up') %>

<h1>Create Account</h1>

<%= nested_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", obj: @user %>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Account Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :display_name, "Display Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :display_name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <%= f.fields_for :organization do |o| %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Organization Information</legend>
      <p>
        <strong>Creating a New Organization:</strong> Fill out the Organization Name field, but leave the Access Code field blank.<br />
        <strong>Joining an Existing Organization:</strong> Fill out both the Organization Name and Access Code field, using the access code that you received from someone at your organization.
      </p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= o.label :name, "Organization Name" %>
        <%= o.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= o.label :access_code, "Organization Access Code" %>
        <%= o.text_field :access_code, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create Account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", :back %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

And, here's the `error_messages` partial:

```
<% if obj.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>There are <%= pluralize(obj.errors.count, "error") %> errors with this form:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get the errors for `User` displaying like they should, just not for `Organization`.  Could it be something to do with only passing `@user` to the partial?

Comment: It would make sense that you are only getting the error messages for the user object if you are only passing in the user, right? In your controller, instead of saying flash.now[:error] = "...", why don't you just say something like flash.now[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages + @organization.errors.full_messages?

Comment: The flash messages actually are not related to this issue.  The problem is with the ActiveModel validations i have setup through the models i believe.  I was assuming that passing `@user` would be ok and the organization errors would come in through `@user.organization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figure out my issue.  Seems i may have had some things backwards with the model associations, or at least with the `accepts_nested_attributes`.

Here are my updated models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  belongs_to :organization

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization

  validates_presence_of :display_name
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Here is my updated create action in my controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
  if params[:user][:organization_attributes][:access_code].blank?
    # create new organization
    @access_code = "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(16)}#{Time.now.to_i}"
    @organization = Organization.create(name: params[:user][:organization_attributes][:name], access_code: @access_code)
    @user.organization_id = @organization.id
    @user.is_admin = true
  else
    # try and add someone to an organization
    @organization = Organization.find(:all, conditions: ["name = ? AND access_code = ?", params[:user][:organization_attributes][:name], params[:user][:organization_attributes][:access_code]])
    if @organization.empty?
      flash.now[:error] = "No organization has been found with that name and access code."
      render :new
      return
    else
      @user.organization_id = @organization.first.id
    end
  end
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been successfully created! Check your email for a confirmation link to activate your account."
    redirect_to sign_in_path
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong! Please try again."
    render :new
  end
end
```

Here is my updated view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign Up') %>

<h1>Create Account</h1>

<%= nested_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", obj: @user %>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Account Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :display_name, "Display Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :display_name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <% @user.build_organization unless @user.organization %>
  <%= f.fields_for :organization do |o| %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Organization Information</legend>
      <p>
        <strong>Creating a New Organization:</strong> Fill out the Organization Name field, but leave the Access Code field blank.<br />
        <strong>Joining an Existing Organization:</strong> Fill out both the Organization Name and Access Code field, using the access code that you received from someone at your organization.
      </p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= o.label :name, "Organization Name" %>
        <%= o.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= o.label :access_code, "Organization Access Code" %>
        <%= o.text_field :access_code, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create Account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", :back %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

Here is my updated error_messages partial (just showing for context - the code changed was not really related to issue):

```
<% if obj.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(obj.errors.count, "error") %> was found with this form:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now, when i try to save without entering any information, all of the correct errors are displayed.  Also, when i enter all the needed user data and leave all of the organization fields blank, the correct organization related validation errors are displayed and the user record is not created.  Works like i needed it to now.